# Limit user connection to only 1 NIC

Tags: linux, ssh, redhat, authentication

On my network, I have a `SERVER` with 3 NICs, each on a separate subnet `A`, `B`, and `C`.
I also have a user, `JOE` who uses SSH to login to `SERVER`

The issue is, `JOE` can log in on any of the interfaces:
`$ ssh joe@server-a
] Welcome to SERVER
exit
$ ssh joe@server-b
] Welcome to SERVER 
exit
$ ssh joe@server-b 
] Welcome to SERVER
exit`

I would like an easy way to prevent `JOE` from logging to the `B` & `C` interfaces. (Alternately, only allow `JOE` to log in to the A interface).

Is this possible? I have hundreds of servers, and I'll have to this to many of them, so simple solutions are preferred.
I'm running Red Hat 7.x
I'm on a closed network, so please don't recommend 3rd party products -- I won't be able to get them.
**TIA!**

Comment: Is it only `Joe` that needs to be restricted, or all users?  Do  you need SSH to be usable on the other interfaces by other accounts?  You could possibly incoming ssh on the other interfaces, but that would apply to everyone.  Or you could run a different ssh daemon bound to specific interfaces with different restrictions.

Comment: IT is just `JOE` that needs the restriction. All other users are OK logging in on any interface. There are other users that need to log in on the other interfaces.

Comment: Hrm, that makes it seem complicated.  I would probably look to see if you can build a `Match` block in your `sshd_config` that restricts an account the way you want.

Comment: What is that? Can you explain?

Comment: Search for match in the [sshd_config](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config) man page.  The 'match' lets you apply restrictions based on user and a few other properties of the connection.  I am not certain if you can use it for this though.

Answer (score 1):

You may try with OpenSSH DenyUsers:

`DenyUsers JOE@serber-b-subnet JOE@serber-c-subnet`

If subnet B is 192.168.0.0:

`DenyUsers JOE@192.168.*`

Comment: Does this go in the sshd_config file, or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, in the sshd_config file.